# What is this 'X' command (with paramters) that uses 24% cpu?

Tags: lightdm, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is process “/usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179785/what-is-process-usr-bin-x-0-auth-var-run-lightdm-root-0-nolisten-tcp-vt7)

This is using about 24% of my CPU's resources.

```
/usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/light/dm/root/:0 -novtswitch -background non
```

Note: the "OH's" could be "ZERO's" as almost no programs including TASK MANAGER list the traditional computer ZERO as 0 which is different from a Narrow O - depending upon the font.

I am running ClamTK in a scan, but with Terror Bite Drives, it's taking HOURS as in 24 hours, the system is slowing right down, maybe due to lack of free space on the SSD, but?

So what does it all mean? Or more exactly what does the  statement mean, in relation to it's component parts - being lightdm and the TCP association?

Answer (score 2):

/usr/bin/X is the program running

:0 is an argument to x telling it to run on display 0 (programmers count 0 first)

-auth /var/run/light/dm/root/:0 I am unsure but probably the lightdm authentication program

-novtswitch not sure if it disables ctrl+shift+F1 through F12 to switch to a vitrual terminal or if it does not switch at init to the vt (display :0 in this case) X runs on

-background none creates a root window with no background

more information can be found here
[What is process "/usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179785/what-is-process-usr-bin-x-0-auth-var-run-lightdm-root-0-nolisten-tcp-vt7/179795#179795)